# Get specific type of polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism, ruby-on-rails-5, polymorphic-associations

I have this model

```
class Article
  belongs_to :source, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :html, foreign_type: "Html", foreign_key: "source_id"
  belongs_to :pdf, foreign_type: "Pdf", foreign_key: "source_id"
end
```

When I set an article with an html source, `pdf` is still found **when html and pdf have the same id**:

```
html.id
=> 1
pdf.id
=> 1

article = Article.create!(source: html)
article.pdf.id
=> 1
```

What am I doing wrong? Isn't the `foreign_type` that tells Rails what to match for the polymorphic association?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to APIdock:

> :foreign_type
>
> Specify the column used to store the associated object’s type, if this is a polymorphic association. By default this is guessed to be
>   the name of the association with a “_type” suffix. So a class that
>   defines a belongs_to :taggable, polymorphic: true association will use
>   “taggable_type” as the default :foreign_type.

So, you should use `foreign_type` in the `source` association to specify what column stores the associated object's type.

I think you want two methods `html` and `pdf`, so you can use it when the source is either `Html` or `Pdf`. In this case, I think you should create two methods for it, for example:

```
def html
  source if source_type == "Html"
end


def pdf
  source if source_type == "Pdf"
end
```

Comment: ah ok, that's simple and easy to understand! Thanks!